# Use a global alert across the react-native app

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I'm a beginner for react-native and I need to alert to the user based on a status which will be retrieved from an API in every 15 seconds. For this I'm using react-native-background-timer in my main component to call the service. But when app is in some other screen (component) even though the service executes perfectly in the main component, it doesn't update it's props or status depending on the result it received (I guess this should be because I'm in a some other screen and props of main component will not be updated). Due to that alert will not be triggered if app is not in the main component

Can anyone please suggest me an approach for this?

```
    class Home extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this._onPopUpShowed = this._onPopUpShowed.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //Initial call after the launch
        this.props.fetchLiveOrderData()

        //Start timer for polling
        const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
            isBackgroudLoad=true
            this.props.fetchLiveOrderData()
        }, 1000*15);
    }


    render(){

        const{payload,isFetching,isError,isSuccess} = this.props.liveOrderData
        return(
           //Render UI depending on the data fetched
        );
    }

}

//map state to props
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        liveOrderData: state.liveOrderData
    }
}

//map dispatch to props
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchLiveOrderData : () => dispatch(fetchLiveOrderData())
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Home)
```

liveOrderReducer.js

```
import {
    FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA, FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA_SUCCESS, FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA_ERROR
} from '../constants'

const initialState = {
    payload: [],
    msg:[],
    isFetching: true,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false
}

export default liveOrderReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA :
            return {
                ...state,
                payload: [],
                msg:[],
                isFetching: true,
                isError: false,
                isSuccess: false
            }
        case FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA_SUCCESS :
            return {
                ...state,
                payload: action.data,
                msg:[],
                isFetching: false,
                isError: false,
                isSuccess:true
            }
        case FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA_ERROR : 
            return {
                ...state,
                payload: [],
                msg:action.msg,
                isFetching: false,
                isError: true,
                isSuccess:false
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

index.js

```
import {
    FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA, FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA_SUCCESS, FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA_ERROR
} from '../constants'
import api from '../lib/api'

export const getLiveOrderData = () => {
    return {
        type : FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA
    }
}

export const getLiveOrderDataSuccess = data => {
    return {
        type : FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA_SUCCESS,
        data
    }
}

export const getLiveOrderDataFailure = () => {
    return {
        type : FETCHING_LIVE_ORDER_DATA_ERROR
    }
}

export const fetchLiveOrderData = () => {
    return(dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getLiveOrderData())
        api.getOrder().then(resp => {
            dispatch(getLiveOrderDataSuccess(resp))
        }).catch((err) => {
            dispatch(getLiveOrderDataFailure(err))
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some code or we cannot help. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please refer the added code snippet. As shown above fetchLiveOrderData() method will be called in every 15 seconds.  Is there anyway that Home component can receive the latest props in the Home component even though app is in some other screen (component). (execution of the componentWillReceiveProps())

Answer (score 0):

Move the notification code to the container or the root component. This will ensure you will receive notifications even if the user moved away from the home screen.

Comment: Home is my main controller and it's where the data fetching is happening. (this.props.fetchLiveOrderData()). My concern is componentWillReceiveProps method will not be called in the Home component when app is in some other screen.